# How to Sort a Store leaving One value

Tags: extjs

I have a variable sequence number in my Data.model . sequence number can be greater or equal to -1. i would like to display the store values (whose sequence number are greater than or equal to 0) sorted in ascending Order.this sorting should ignore records with sequence number -1 and display that at the last.

Comment: See: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-sortType

Comment: What you tried for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `sorters` confing of your store and custom function to sort with `sorterFn` property.

[Working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/12gv)

```
sorters: [{
    sorterFn: function(record1, record2) {
        var data1 = record1.get('sortValue'),
            data2 = record2.get('sortValue');

        if(data1 === -1) {
            return 1;
        }

        if(data1 === data2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if(data1 < data2) {
                return -1;
            } else if (data1 > data2) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}],
```